# No app in java.library.path

Tags: java

I have app.jar in my lib folder at eclipse project. However, when I run my function, which are using app.jar. I get error no app in java.library.path. I have no idea what should I do.

Comment: Did you add lib folder to project's class path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java's java.library.path used to specify native libraries directories, you should add you app.jar to java classpath:`java -cp app.jar;your/classes/*; com.your.Class`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the code in app.jar tries to load a native library (a *.dll file if you're using windows). The dll is most likely inside your jar file, but could also be shipped seperately. Try providing an explicit java.library.path:

`java -Djava.library.path=lib YourMainClass`

or

`java -Djava.library.path=lib/app.jar YourMainClass`

I'm unsure if the second one works like this. SWT for example loads its native library from inside a jar, but I think they added some code of their own to achieve this. Try looking for the dll file first. It may not be arround at all.

Comment: I have GWT project and when I added this to running argument I have errors

Comment: Could you please specify in more detail. What OS are you running, what errors do you get (before and after, including stacktrace), which version of GWT and what are the exact runtime arguments you're using?

Comment: OS: windows
Error: 
Unknown argument: -Djava.library.path=war/WEB-INF/lib
Version: Google Web Toolkit 2.4.0

Comment: well, I can't help you unless you provide a detailed report of what went wrong. "Unknown argument" is **a bit** vague. maybe this helps? 
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/GWT_2_0_RC

Comment: I click run project, but I have seen red inscription: Unknown argument: -Djava.library.path=war/WEB-INF/lib. I don't know what I can tell you more.